# Generating a new RDD variable from two large-scale RDDs

Tags: apache-spark

I have two large size RDDs as below.

```
#First RDD
key1   value1 labelA
key2   value2 lableB
.....

#Second RDD
stepA key1 value1
stepB key2 value2
...
```

And, what I want to extract is as below.

```
labelA stepA key1 value1 
labelB stepB key2 value2
```

However, my problem is that the two RDDs size is very large. So, join might be takes a lot of time. I want to avoid a join method and want to reduce the shuffle size as possible. And also, collecting one RDD and making it a broadcast variables didn't work because of its size. Note that RDD size is more than 10 gigabytes, which means that the driver cannot store them at once.

Therefore, is there any way to achieve generating a new RDD from two large size RDD? As I mentioned above, I want to avoid join method.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add more details about the RDDs. How does the current data look like? how do you want the new RDD to look like? How will the data in the new RDD will be derived? Please [edit] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: There are several ways to combine RDDs: union, join... but we do not know what you want to do ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have RDDs of 3-tuples, this should give you what you want.

```
val left_rdd = rdd1
    .map{ case (key, value, label) => (key, value) -> label }
val right_rdd = rdd2
    .map{ case (step, key, value) => (key, value) -> step }
left_rdd.join(right_rdd)
    .map{ case ((key, value), (label, step)) => (label, step, key, value) }
```

You should try it before assuming that it will be too long. 10GB is not that big. Shuffle should be avoided **if possible** in spark. But sometimes, that's just exactly what you need.